# How can I connect to MS Dynamics 365 CRM with SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365, ssms-2012

I'm trying to connect to MS Dynamics 365 CRM with SQL Server Management Studio. After lots of researching I can't find any solution that how can I connect database.

Comment: Is Dynamics 365 "on premise", or in the cloud ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to Dynamics365 (at least when it's "in the cloud") using SSMS following this recipe here:

https://markcarrington.dev/2020/05/13/cds-t-sql-endpoint-pt-1-connecting/

Basically, you need to explicitly enable the TDS endpoint in the Power Platform admin area and then use `yourcrm.crm.dynamics.com,5558` as the server/instance name, and some Azure Active Directory authentication scheme to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do with SQL, you can also use the `SQL 4 CDS` plugin for the `XRM Toolbox`

More information on the `SQL 4 CDS` plugin is available [here](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/MarkMpn.SQL4CDS/)

> SQL 4 CDS allows you to use standard SQL syntax to query and manipulate your data and metadata in CDS / D365.
>
> Supports
>
> - SELECT
> - INSERT
> - UPDATE
> - DELETE
>
> Where possible the queries are converted to FetchXML, allowing you to
> generate FetchXML queries for plugins or integrations by writing
> familiar SQL and converting it.
>
> Using the preview T-SQL endpoint, SELECT queries can also be run that
> aren't convertible to FetchXML.

---

**EDIT** I just realised that the author of this plugin is the same as the author of the article in the other answer